# Nested round bars java library android compatible

Tags: java, android, plot, nested

I was wondering if there is any java library that creates nested rounded progress bars as shown in this [link](http://hmaidasani.github.io/RadialChartImageGenerator/). The second part of the question is: If that java library exists, is it android compatible?

[image]

Comment: No one answering? :(